# Bitcoin Core wallet update schedule and transaction

Tags: bitcoind

1) Currently I have Bitcoin Core QT for MS windows 64bit - 32bit version 0.11.2 (yellow one with the most porpularity). Is there any scheduled update of QT to higher version in a near future?

2) I heard from someone that if the Bitcoin Core wallet (same as the above. MS windows 64 bit- 32 bit in yellow color) for each of owner is NOT the same (i.e one has 0.11.0 ver and other has 0.11.2) and receiver's wallet is not synchronized with BTC P2P network, sending BTC from one wallet to other is not feasible and lost permanently. Is this true?

Comment: Bitcoin Core 0.12.0 is very close to being released (days).

Answer (score 1):

Different versions of the Bitcoin-qt wallets can most certainly send and receive bitcoins from each other. They are compatible. And it looks like it will stay compatible for the foreseeable future as no hard forks are planned near term.

Just make sure you use the "official" client from bitcoin.org and check signatures to make sure you get the correct one. Also try things with small amounts of money to make yourself comfortable with how it works.

All the other wallets mentioned at bitcoin.org are also compatible regarding sending and receiving bitcoins by the way, but I'm assuming you're interested in running a full node i.e. bitcoin-qt.

Note that this site is not affiliated with bitcoin.org or the core developers (although some of them post here sometimes). I'll clean up your question to better fit the purpose of this website. One way to contact core developers is through the #bitcoin IRC channel.